# Gather info from HTML forms with PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

This is what I got.

**formulario.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN">

<html>
<head>
<title> Surveys </title>
</head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv=Content-Type>
<body>
<form action="main2.php" method="post">

    Number of Surveys <input type="number" name="number">
    <input type="submit" value="Send"/>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**main2.php**

```
<html>
<body>

<?

function Survey($number){

    if($number > 0){ 
        $a = 1;
        while ($a <= $number){ ?>
<h2>Survey for person number <? echo $a;?></h2> 
<form action="resultados.php" method="post">
Age <input type="number" name="age"/> <br><br>
Genre <br><br>
<input type="radio" name="male" value="6"/> Male <br>
<input type="radio" name="female" value="7"/> Female <br><br>
Marital Status <br><br>
<input type="radio" name="single" value="1"/> Single <br>
<input type="radio" name="married" value="2"/> Married <br>
<input type="radio" name="divorced" value="3"/> Divorced <br>
<input type="radio" name="free" value="4"/> Free Union <br>
<input type="radio" name="widowed" value="5"/> Widowed <br><br>
<?          
            $a = $a + 1;
        }
    }
}
echo Survey($_POST['number']);


?>

<input type="submit" value="Send"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**resultados.php**

```
<?

function Calculate($age){
    $array_of_ages = array();
    $array_of_ages[] = $age;
    var_dump($array_of_ages);
}

echo Calcular($_POST['age']);
?>
```

I want to create a little survey, so in the "formulario.php" file I select an amount of people to go on "main2.php" and create the survey for each.  For example, if I select 3 persons, what "main2.php" code should do is to create 3 surveys, one after another, in the same page with only a "submit" buttom.  Then, when I "fill all the surveys and press the submit buttom what I'm trying to do with "resultados.php" is to get all the data gathered from those forms and do some stuff like, counting how many people is married or divorced, an average of age in women and men, etc... and show them, after I press "Send".

The problem is that I'm stuck and I don't have any clue on how to do it. I've searched about in ways to catch the info like, arrays, loops, but none of it works.  As you can see, I created "resultados.php" where I would supposely show the info processed but no luck.

Depending on which number I select in the first .php file, the "while" in the "main2.php" creates the amount of surveys suggested, but I don't know if it's the right way to do it, according for what I want to reach.

I'll appreciate any help on this. I just started to learn PHP this week and I'm frustrated now because I can't figure out how to solve it by my own.

PD: Sorry for my english, not my native language.

Comment: Why are you giving the same survey 3 times to one person? Shouldn't each visitor get 1 survey no matter what?

Comment: I know, but in order to acomplish what I'm trying to do, I'm just "printing" all the surveys in one page to collect data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first important thing is, your `<form>` tag is *inside* the `while` loop. Though your form is closing only once, it's opening several times which results in an invalid HTML. So place it  before the `while` loop this way:

```
$a = 1; ?>
<form action="resultados.php" method="post">
<? while ($a <= $number){ ?>
<h2>Survey for person number <? echo $a;?></h2>
```

Second thing, since you have *age* repeating multiple times in your form, you should make it as an HTML input array, only then it can hold multiple values, so change this your *age* input's `name` attribute to:

```
<!-- `[]` tells the HTML that all values of input with this name should
be preserved. If you do not have this, only your last value will be passed -->
<input type="number" name="age[]"/>
```

Another thing to consider is your radio buttons, radio buttons work as group, now logically someone filling the form cannot be checking both *male* and *female,* right? So you should group them so that only one is filled, you do this again by changing the `name` attribute:

```
<!-- Again the `[]` is added because you have it repeating.-->
<input type="radio" name="gender[]" value="6"/> Male <br>
<input type="radio" name="gender[]" value="7"/> Female <br><br>
```

Lastly, since *age* is an array, you need to loop through the values at the PHP side:

```
function Calculate($age){
    foreach($age as $ages)
    {
      echo $ages;
    }
}
```

Comment: I managed to catch the ages of every survey thanks to your suggestions, but now it seems radio buttons don't work as I expected.  Making them to be placed in an input array, when I create more than one survey in the **formulario.php** page, they work like if all of the buttons were into a whole group, instead of group them by survey.

Comment: @SeanSabe Have you put the radio buttons into two separate groups? One for the _Genre_ and another for the _Marital Status._

Comment: Yes, sir. I named **gender[]** for Genre and **marital_state[]** for Marital Status, but isn't working.  For example. When I select **Single** in the first survey and the go below, to the other survey and select **Married** the radio button of the first survey unchecks.

Comment: @SeanSabe I totally get what you mean, in that case our array is going to be a bit longer, we will be adding another index to our array and you would need 2 `foreach`. Check out [this code](http://pastebin.com/Z56r1YaS) and modify accordingly.

Comment: The code was very useful. I realized it was easier to understand using **echo** to separate code than how I mixed HTML with PHP, using the **<?** everytime I needed to switch between codes.  I managed to get almost done what I was reaching. Though, I'm stuck again. I've tried to get a value from a variable in one **.php** file and use it in other **.php** file, but I can't solve it.  I've tried _global_ variables and _include_ methods, but no luck.

Comment: @SeanSabe For sharing values across multiple pages, **[session](http://www.sitepoint.com/php-sessions/)** is the perfect method. Try it and let me know if you face any other problems ^-^

Comment: I'm using **$_POST** to get a value to work with, so I stored it in a variable **$number = $_POST['number']**, it catches the quantity of surveys I submit in the firs _.php file_. Then, I need to use that value in a function I defined in the second _.php file_ to calculate an average, according of the number of surveys entered (the value catched by the $_POST method), but that's where the problem starts. I tried _SESSIONS_ but I don't know if I'm doing it wrong, because it seems to work with defined values while I need to use the value catched and assing it to the SESSION method.

Comment: @SeanSabe You could make up a new question on it instead of this prolonged discussion ^-^

Comment: Alright, mate. Here is. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23437826/is-it-possible-to-have-session-post)