# Is it possible to have $_SESSION = $_POST?

Tags: php, html, forms, session, post

I don't know if I'm doing wrong but let's say I have this.

**formulario.php**

```
<? session_start(); 
   $_SESSION['promedio'] = $number; 
   echo '
   <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN">
   <html>

   <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv=Content-Type>
   <body>
   <form action="main3.php" method="post">

   Número de Encuestas <input type="number" name="number">
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar"/>

   </form>
   </body>
   </html> ';

   ?>
```

Now, in **main3.php**

```
<?
  session_start();

  $number = $_POST['number'];
  $_SESSION['promedio'] = $number;


  function Calcular($edades, $estado_civil, $genero){
  global $number;
foreach($edades as $edad){} 
echo "El promedio de edad general es: ".((array_sum($edades))/$number)."<br>";


$x; 
$y; 
$z; 
$w; 
$v;
$u;
$t;
foreach ($genero as $i) {
    foreach ($i as $j) {
        if($j == "Hombres")
        {
            $u++;
        }
        if($j == "Mujeres")
        {
            $t++;
        }
        $count_values[$j]++;
    }
}
echo "Cantidad de hombres: ".$u."<br>",
     "Cantidad de mujeres: ".$t."<br>"; 
foreach ($estado_civil as $a) {
    foreach ($a as $b) {
        if($b == "Soltero")
        {
            $x++;;
        }
        if($b == "Casado")
        {
            $y++;
        }
        if($b == "Separado")
        {
            $z++;
        }
        if($b == "Libre")
        {
            $w++;
        }
        if($b == "Viudo")
        {
            $v++;
        }
        $count_values[$b]++;
    }
}
echo "Cantidad de personas solteras: ".$x."<br>", 
     "Cantidad de personas casadas: ".$y."<br>",
     "Cantidad de personas separadas: ".$z."<br>",
     "Cantidad de personas en unión libre: ".$w."<br>",
     "Cantidad de personas viudas: ".$v."<br>";

  }

  echo '<form type="submit" action="resultados.php" method="post">';
  for ($i=0; $i < $number; $i++) { 

  echo '
  <html>
  <h2>Datos de la persona '.$i.'</h2> 
  Edad <input type="number" name="edades[]"/> <br><br>
  Sexo <br><br>
  <input type="radio" name="genero['.$i.'][]" value="Hombres"/> Masculino <br>
  <input type="radio" name="genero['.$i.'][]" value="Mujeres"/> Femenino <br><br>
  Estado Civil <br><br>
  <input type="radio" name="estado_civil['.$i.'][]" value="Soltero"/> Soltero <br>
  <input type="radio" name="estado_civil['.$i.'][]" value="Casado"/> Casado <br>
  <input type="radio" name="estado_civil['.$i.'][]" value="Separado"/> Separado <br>
  <input type="radio" name="estado_civil['.$i.'][]" value="Libre"/> Unión Libre <br>
  <input type="radio" name="estado_civil['.$i.'][]" value="Viudo"/> Viudo <br><br> ';
  }

  echo '
  <input type="submit">
  </form>
  </html> ';

  ?>
```

Last file **resultados.php**

```
<?
include ("main3.php");
echo Calcular($_POST['edades'], $_POST['estado_civil'], $_POST['genero']);

?>
```

So, as you can see, I call the **$number** variable into a function and this is where the problem is. It keeps saying I'm dividing by zero, which means **$number** isn't saving the value through **$_SESSION** when I call it in **Average()**.  I've some things to get this to work, but no luck.

Any suggestion or help about what I'm missing would be appreciated.

Comment: The `$number` variable is not defined in the scope of the function: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: Your code doesn't even use the session, even though it looks like it does.

Comment: @jeroen I tried with _global_ and didn't work.

Comment: Why does divide by zero mean that it isn't saving the function through `$_SESSION`?

Comment: Another thing you could do is, change this line `$number = $_POST['number'];` to `$number = isset($_POST['number'])?$_POST['number']:$_SESSION['promedio'];` So even if you call the `Calcular` function on another page, your `$number` value is still preserved because of saving it into session.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that when you submit the form in `main3.php` to `resultados.php`, there's no `number` input. You can add it as a hidden input in the second form:

```
echo '<form type="submit" action="resultados.php" method="post">';
echo "<input type='hidden' name='number' value='$number'>";
```

Also, you shouldn't output `<html>` in the `for` loop in `main3.php`.

Comment: I tried before and didn't work with _global_ method. Really I know the variable scope is a simple thing but isn't working either.

Comment: The last time someone said that, it was because they put the `global` declaration outside the function. It has to be _inside_ the function.

Comment: Believe me, I can be very new for PHP but not to that point. I defined _global_ inside the fucntion and didn't work.

Comment: Please add the code that didn't work to your question. I've never had `global` fail on me.

Comment: You're new enough to confuse assigning to `$_SESSION` with reading from it, so I'm not giving you the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: Can you please show the code that isn't working? The code you posted never even calls `Average()`.

Comment: There you have. I put the real code. It's in spanish, though.

Comment: The form that submits to `resultados.php` doesn't have a `number` input. So when it includes `main3.php`, `$_POST['number']` is empty.

Comment: Sorry, mate but I don't get you. What shall I do? I just need to grab the value taken by **$_POST** from **formulario.php** and use it in **Calcular** function.

Comment: OK, I've posted a new answer.

Comment: @Barnar Yes, it solved it. Though, it post the answers in **main3.php**, below the surveys, it does what it has to do.